# How to create set of related properties?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a collection `foos` of type `Foo`

Every `Foo` has a property `Position`

A `Position` is struct holding coordinates

```
struct Position
{
    Position(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    int X { get; private set; }
    int Y { get; private set; }
    int Z { get; private set; }
}
```

I have a bunch of methods that act on either X, Y or Z.

```
void DoX(int whichX)
{
    var set = foos.Where(p => p.X == whichX);
    //..lots of code
}

void DoY(int whichY)
{
    var set = foos.Where(p => p.Y == whichY);
    //..lots of repeating code
}
```

That code yells refactor me!
What I would like to do is:

```
void Do(int which, something theDimension)
{
    var set = foos.Where(p => p.[how to get X/Y/Z] == which);
    //..lots of non-repeating code
}
```

I solved it by adding an enum `Dimensions`

```
enum Dimensions
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

And adding a `Dimension` method on `Position`:

```
int Dimension(Dimensions d)
{
    switch (d)
    {
        case Dimensions.X:
            return X;
        case Dimensions.Y:
            return Y;
        case Dimensions.Z:
            return Z;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument");    
    }           
}
```

So that now I can call `Do` like this:

```
void Do(int which, Dimensions d)
{
    var set = foos.Where(p => p.Dimension(d) == which);
    // .. stuff ..
}
```

However, that seems a very contrived way of going about. From experience I know my code always ends up complicating things more than needed. My question is: how can this be simplified?

Comment: This might be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: If you can flesh the code example out to meet Code Review's standards, this is better dealt with there. It's too broad and primarily opinion based, which make it unsuitable for Stack Overflow. That said, if the pattern is occurring in your code frequently, and your enum-based approach is helping simplify the code, that seems like a good thing to me. Main thing I might change is make the enum a `[Flags]` enum so that things like comparisons can be applied across more than just one dimension. That said, it's hard to know even whether that's a good idea, given the lack of context.

Comment: @PeterDuniho In this case [Flags] would not be useful but I appreciate the suggestion, in the real-time project I am actually using it for other stuff. I sort of hoped someone would chime in and say 'no, better use this approach' before  being referred to Code Review. I suppose I should have seen that coming. Tx anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way depending on the bigger picture, but another option that might be a little faster...

```
public void Do(Func<Position, int> dimension)
        {
            foos.Where(p => dimension(p) > 0).ToList();
        }
```

then on your position

```
    public static int FX(Position p) => p.X;
    public static int FY(Position p) => p.Y;
    public static int FZ(Position p) => p.Z;
```

then  do

```
  Do(Position.FX);
```

or without pre done functions on Position you can do...

```
Do(p => p.X);
```

Or another way completely.... ( no range checking, but you can add it )

```
struct Position
{
    private int[] _values;
    Position(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        _values = new []{x, y, z};
    }
    public int X => _values[0]; 
    public int Y => _values[1]; 
    public int Z => _values[2];
    public int this[int dimension] => _values[dimension];
}
```

and then

```
 public void Do(int d)
        {
            foos.Where(p => p[d] > 0).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Fascinating. Will need some time processing what is actually happening there.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven added another way.....which may be the fastest ( not sure, I haven't tried to time it )